# Spring Data JPA Custom Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter

I'm having some issues when trying to implement Custom Repositorys with Spring Data JPA.

I try follow some references guides like this but I cant find the problem:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

I do not know why Spring tries to look up the custom repository method as my entity property.

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa => 1.5.11.RELEASE
```

Entity:

```
public class MyEntity {

    private Integer id
    private String name;

    // Getter/Setters...
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {


    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    //...

    public MyDTO customFind(Long id){


        return repository.customFind(id);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>, MyCustomRepository {

    //no-op
}
```

Custom Repository:

```
public interface MyCustomRepository {

    List<MyDTO> customFind(Long id);

}
```

Custom Repository Impl:

```
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl implements MyCustomRepository {


    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public List<MyDTO> customFind(Long id){


        JPAQuery<EmpregadoEntity> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
        MyDTO myDTO = query...  //... JPA query return MyDTO

        return myDTO;

    }
}
```

When i run the application i got PropertyReferenceException:

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property customFind found for type MyEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:335)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:311)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:274)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rename class "MyCustomRepository" to "MyRepositoryCustom" to fix the problem.

Now works fine!  =)

Answer (score 0):

The type of entity and ID that it works with,MyEntity and  Long, are specified in the generic parameters on `JpaRepository`. That is what your custom repository should be working with. So your `MyCustomRepositoryImpl` should use *MyEntity* instead of *MyDTO*.