# Spring data JPA to filter by multiple fields and return projections

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa, spring-data

I am working on a PoC of a simple RESP API with a MySQL database. I am using Spring Data JPA and Spring Web. I think my my use case is very common and yet I haven't found the best solution. Here is the details.

1. For the sake of the discussion, let's use an entity `Person` with say 50 different fields/columns (e.g. `id`, `name`, `age`, etc.)
2. I want to expose a simple HTTP GET endpoint that would return a JSON with a list of people. I want to offer the user the following request params:

   - `withName` to filter by name.
   - `withAge` to filter by age.
   - ... some other `withXXX`, although not as many as the number of fields. Let's say 5 more.
   - `sortBy` to sort
   - `page` and `pageSize` to paginate.
   - `fields` to decide what fields the user wants to get in the response
3. An example of a possible call would be:

```
GET /people?withName=Charly&withAge=30&withCountry=esp&sortBy=name&page=1&pageSize=10&fields=id,surname,genre

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "surname": "Smith",
        "genre": "male"
    },
    {
        "id": 45,
        "surname": "Doe",
        "genre": "female"
    },
    ...
]
```

Now, after having read here and there, I think it would be good to have the following:

- Use DTO (Spring projections) because I don't want to get the 50 columns from the database if it's not required (see `fields` request param).
- Use perhaps specifications because the fields to filter with are chosen by the user in the request.
- Use standard sorting and pagination features offered by JPA/Spring data.

I was expecting this use case to be very common, but I am surprised that I haven't found it anywhere else. This makes me think that I am doing something wrong.

Do I need to implement this "manually" using queries or criteria? I expect to have a high number of entities and was expecting not to have to implement this for every one of them.

I saw this [interesting article](https://blog.tratif.com/2017/11/23/effective-restful-search-api-in-spring/), but it isn't using projections, which I think it's important.
I also have read articles in Baeldung, in [Vlad Mihalcea's site](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), in [Thorben Janssen's site](https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/) and, of course, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692391/how-to-use-projections-and-specifications-with-spring-data-jpa), all related to the use of DTO, projections, etc., but again, I haven't found anywhere an example mixing Spring data, projections with a dynamic number of fields, filtering using multiple fields and pagination.

I am started to think that I am asking too much, but I see this scenario and think that people must have faced it many times in the past.

Can anybody help, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not sure what you expect how this could work - of course you have to implement how your entities are queried using the attributes, JPA doesn't know that `withCountry=esp` should result in a "=" check, should it ignore the case? Should it do transformations? etc. Also, you have to make sure that users don't query attributes that aren't present on entities so that your query ends up throwing an exception.
Also, opening up a database to all sorts of requests supporting a generic filtering language for users is already possible - with SQL :-)

Comment: We can rename `withName=John` to `name=John` where `name` corresponds to a field of `Person` if that makes it easier. My point is that I'd like to offer a flexible API and internally use as much Spring data features as I can to avoid having to write boiler plate code. I am far from being an expert in Spring data, so not sure what it can offer. I see what it can offer when returning entities, but when I try to use DTO and projections, things get trickier. For instance, having this fixed would be helpful https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1033, but it isn't. I wish there was a workaround?

Comment: In order to try to narrow the discussion down: I can take care of validating the request parameters, let's forget about it. Also, I don't intend to offer the power of SQL to the clients. Just the option to filter by a number of different fields, always with "=". Specifications help here, as well as queries by example. I mean, there are tools and features out there to deal with my requirements, or that I think, but I can't quite find the right combination that suits my scenario.