# How does JPA EntityGraph allow chosing the entity graph at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have seen various post describing that JPA EntityGraph allows to choose the graph at run time. And I am not entirely clear what this refers to.

Out of good faith and respect I would like to take this helpful article for reference: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph. (Most of JPA users might have gone through it already.)

The article quotes -

> EntityGraph allows grouping the related persistence fields which we
> want to retrieve and lets us choose the graph type at runtime.

and again solidifies above statement in conclusion section.

> In this article, we've explored using the JPA Entity Graph to
> dynamically fetch an Entity and its associations.
>
> The decision is made at runtime in which we choose to load or not the
> related association.

As we see in the article (5.1) - EntityGraphs are defined as below using Annotations-
**5.1. Defining an Entity Graph with Annotations**

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "post-entity-graph",
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("subject"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("user"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("comments"),
  }
)
@Entity
public class Post {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //...
}
```

**The @NameEntityGraph annotation is defined at compile time and I don't see anything runtime or dynamic here.**

**But in 5.2** - entity graphs are defined using api or programmatically -
**5.2. Defining an Entity Graph with the JPA API**

```
 EntityGraph<Post> entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Post.class);
 entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("subject");
 entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("user");
```

***In 5.2 approach, I see nodes can be chosen dynamically using some logic. So is this approach is what is refered to "dynamically fetch" and "runtime based".***
Or am i missing something and do i have more to understand.

Further the approaches given in **6. Using the Entity Graph**
ex:

```
EntityGraph entityGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("post-entity-graph");
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);
Post post = entityManager.find(Post.class, id, properties);
```

are all programmatic and so can be changed during runtime i.e they can be said as dynamic.
But one approach missed in above article, but mentioned here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs, as below, does not seem to fit in to dynamic criteria.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Item.characteristics")
    Item findByName(String name);
}
```

**So does the dynamic approach just refer to 5.2 style or it implies even 5.1 style too.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use dynamic entity graphs with spring-data, because `JpaRepository` doesn't have methods to pass entity graphs like

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id, EntityGraph entityGraph);
```

**Using custom JPA repository**

You can use raw JPA for that, by creating a custom repository and using entity graphs with `EntityManager`.

**Using spring-data-jpa-entity-graph**

There is a more convenient approach by using library 
[spring-data-jpa-entity-graph](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph).

It allows to use JPA repository methods like `findById()` or `findByName()` with dynamic entity graphs.

I prefer to use it with this helper class

```java
public abstract class EntityGraphBuilder<T> {

    private List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    protected T self;

    public T add(String path) {
        result.add(path);
        return self;
    }

    public DynamicEntityGraph build() {
        return new DynamicEntityGraph(EntityGraphType.FETCH, result);
    }

}
```

Each entity has its own `GraphBuilder`

```java
@Entity
public class OrderEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private OrderRequestEntity orderRequest;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ProviderEntity provider;

    public static GraphBuilder graph() {
        return new GraphBuilder();
    }

    public static class GraphBuilder extends EntityGraphBuilder<GraphBuilder> {

        private GraphBuilder() {
            self = this;
        }

        public GraphBuilder orderRequest() {
            return add("orderRequest");
        }

        public GraphBuilder provider() {
            return add("provider");
        }

    }

}
```

Repository uses `EntityGraphJpaRepository` from `spring-data-jpa-entity-graph` library

```
@Repository
public interface OrdersRepository extends EntityGraphJpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {

  OrderEntity findByName(String name, EntityGraph entityGraph);

}
```

You can use derived query methods like `findByName()` with dynamic entity graphs too.

Example of using `findById()` method, the same approach can be applied to `findByName()`

```
OrdersRepository ordersRepository;
Long orderId = 1L;

OrderEntity order = ordersRepository.findById(
  orderId,
  OrderEntity.graph().orderRequest().provider().build()
).orElseThrow(
  () -> new ServiceException("Can't find orderId=" + orderId)
);
```

Comment: very much appreciate for bringing in new libarary ++1

Comment: @samshers Always ready to help. You can try my approach, it is production ready.

Comment: I am [spring-data-jpa-entity-graph](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph) maintainer. @v.ladynev , [Type safe EntityGraphs](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph#type-safe-entitygraph) will allow you to remove a lot of code :)

Comment: @RédaHousniAlaoui Thank you for a good library. We are havy using it in production. It is cool that you have updated the library to the last Spring version. I appreciate it very much and going to use the last version. I don't like code generation. Also I don't like this `____` in the fluent API. I am okay to have a lot of the code on the low level (model, utils etc.) to have good code quality on the user (developer) level.

Comment: Well, I could allow customization of `____`.
> I don't like code generation
I distinguish 2 types of code generation. The one that is provided by Maven/Gradle plugin that I also dislike.
But this one is provided by an Annotation Processor (SPI provided by the JDK). It is triggered by a simple call to `javac`.  

Anyway, happy you have been using the lib in production :)

Answer (score 2):

With spring-data from [jpa-buddy blog](https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/dynamic-entity-graphs-in-spring-data-jpa/):

> *"Fortunately, this framework allows adding any arbitrary string between the repository method's find and By parts. So, in the repository, there will be two methods"*

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "pets.type", "pets.visits" })
Optional<Owner> findById(Integer id);

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "pets "})
Optional<Owner> findOwnerWithPetsById(Integer id);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do like findAllOwnerWithPets() ?

Comment: No, in addition to the EntityGraph you can leverage @Query annotation with join fetch.

Answer (score 1):

In the Baeldung article, **Section 5** is only about various ways to define a graph with not much emphasis on the dynamic/non-dynamic nature of the definition itself.

In **Section 5.1** the definition of the graph is static but this section is only about demonstrating how to define a graph which then will be used in typical cases when building the graph dynamically is not really necessary. This section shows an alternative to the older way of building HQL / JPA-QL queries with JOIN FETCH sections.

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "post-entity-graph",
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("subject"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("user"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("comments"),
  }
)
@Entity
public class Post {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //...
}
```

Then, **Section 6** tells you how to use the entity graphs defined earlier in various ways.

```
// Getting the "statically" defined graph (from annotation)
EntityGraph entityGraph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("post-entity-graph");

// Then using the graph
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);
Post post = entityManager.find(Post.class, id, properties);
```

Naturally, you can swap this first line to the fully dynamically built graph demonstrated in Section 5.2:

```
// Building the graph dynamically
EntityGraph<Post> entityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Post.class);
entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("subject");
entityGraph.addAttributeNodes("user");


// Then using the graph
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", entityGraph);
Post post = entityManager.find(Post.class, id, properties);
```

In both cases you supply an **EntityGraph** object to the query.

Comment: `In both cases you supply an EntityGraph object to the query.`. Gr8 answer. ++1.  You said, `"This section shows an alternative to the older way of building HQL / JPA-QL queries with JOIN FETCH sections."` so this vs/or NamedEntityGraph. Right?

Comment: "so this vs/or NamedEntityGraph. Right? " - Yes