# How to filter dynamically against a DTO result in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, filter, spring-data-jpa

I used `Spring Data JPA Specifications` for dynamically filtering against entities in some `Spring Boot` apps and now trying to apply the same logic for `DTO` instead of `entity` classes.

However, as far as I see on [some threads](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2959) e.g. it seems to be not supported:

> We currently do not support DTO projections because we do not differentiate what to select, we just select the entity Root

So, what is a proper approach for dynamically filtering and sorting a list of `DTO` object? I tried to create a custom filtering method as shown below but not sure if there is a better approach for this purpose. So, how to filter a list of `DTO` result dynamically in `Spring Boot` with `Kotlin`?

```
class AccountDtoFilter(private val filterDTO: AccountFilterDTO) : Specification<AccountDTO> {

    companion object {

        fun createPredicate(filterDTO: AccountFilterDTO): Predicate? {
            val predicates = mutableListOf<Predicate>()

            if (filterDTO.name != null) {
                val namePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get<String>("name"), "%${filterDTO.name}%")
                predicates.add(namePredicate)
            }

            if (filterDTO.email != null) {
                val emailPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.get<String>("email"), "%${filterDTO.email}%")
                predicates.add(emailPredicate)
            }

            // other filtering fields

            return if (predicates.isEmpty()) null else criteriaBuilder.and(*predicates.toTypedArray())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered [QueryDSL](http://querydsl.com/) as an option to use instead of Specifications?

Comment: @Toni I have not used it, but I will check. So, for this scenario, would it be the most proper solution to apply dynamic filtering to a complex data model or projection instead of directly applying to an entity?

Comment: I think so, yes. I can write down the answer with more details later today.

Comment: Here is [the useful article](https://good-mood.medium.com/spring-data-jpa-querydsl-taking-best-from-both-worlds-2bd80af9d0a9) I found regarding QueryDsl. Although it's written in Java, but should be pretty straightforward to switch it to Kotlin.

Comment: @Toni Could it be used for building dynamic filtering against `DTO` instead of `Entity` via `JPA` as it is done with `Spring Data Specifications`?

Comment: Yes, you have to handle the result properly for more details check [this](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.4.2/reference/html/ch03s02.html).

Comment: There is also an option to create a view (containing the fields of the DTO) on the database level and define it as a read-only entity ([link](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-views/)). So you can use specifications for dynamic filtering against the view instead of entity.

Comment: @Toni Then, specifications for dynamic filtering can be used against an entity or view, but not against projection. Right?

Comment: Since Spring 3.0 you can use specifications with projections, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75886772/10231374), but also check comments.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is a good idea to mimic a database behaviour (filtering of several objects by a ruleset) in memory with your own code?

To me it looks as if you are starting to build an in-memory database here, is this your intention? Then you could as well use one that is already built, put your DTOs there and then query it to filter.

Or use the `filter` methods of any collection where you put your DTOs.

Probably you have to step back from your database-centered view on the DTOs to a more object-related view. Your examples look like a nice use case for the `contains` method of strings.

Comment: Actually I would prefer to apply filter directly via some `Spring Data JPA` features, but as far as I see it seems to be not possible for now. So, I am trying to find a proper way to apply dynamic filtering to a resultset and it could be a projection, dto, etc. as I have a complex data model. What would you suggest in this situation? Would it be possible to apply dynamic filtering to a projection?

Comment: You should try to filter the data with the query to the database and then apply the projection. This way the database can optimize your query. The other way around you would have to do the "query"/filter optimization.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, when specifications are used query is formed using predicates, which means filtering is performed on the database level and not in memory.

Comment: @Toni exactly, but this only works for the entities and not for the projection to DTOs. I didn't mean that OP should write SQL statements and link it somehow to JPA.

Comment: Yes, that's why at first I tried to use specifications against complex data model as I used before on entities, but unfortunately it is not supported. For this reason, I am looking for an approach that provides dynamic filtering.